# Prefixing a symbol to username in URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a username system in my app, and I'm trying to make the URLs pretty. I'd rather not have anything like:

**myapp.com/users/joebloggs**

**myapp.com/u/joebloggs**

but rather

**myapp.com/joebloggs**

If I want the pretty version I'm going to have to whitelist a whole load of paths, which I'd rather not do. I noticed that Medium.com and producthunt.com do the following to solve this:

**myapp.com/@joebloggs**

How do I go about creating the same in a Rails 6 app where the @ symbol is prefixed to the username? Pretty sure I have to namespace the routes, but unsure how to implement it exactly. I thought something like the following might work, but it doesn't.

```
namespace :user, path: "@:username" do
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: What does `rails routes` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prefix the route with the `@` symbol and follow it with the variable name you want to capture, for instance:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '@:user_id' => 'users#show'
```

and then in your controller, just refer to the variable name like so:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: { user_id: params[:user_id] }.to_json
  end
end
```

This is what you'll get:

```
// http://localhost:3000/@joe

{
  "user_id": "joe"
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to scope pages for that particular `@user` you can do as well, using the same technique:

```
  # config/routes.rb

  scope '@:user_id' do
    get 'scoped', to: 'users#scoped'
  end
```

```
http://localhost:3000/@joe/scoped
```

Comment: Scoped it as per your edit, and it works great. Thanks.